# Is "thank you so much" equal to "thank you" nowadays?

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

I recently came to the US. Sometimes people use "thank you so much" where I only expect a simple "thank you" after a simple favor (like holding the door), and I find myself doing the similar thing: adding "so much" to "thank you" all the time.

Is it the new norm to use "thank you so much" instead of "thank you" regardless of the extra gratitude?

Comment: I don’t think there is an authoritative answer. The “so much” adds a gushing gratitude that is  in truth almost meaningless. But this is now merely a matter of taste and personal usage.

Comment: What situations? Are we talking shopworkers? Business clients? Friends? Family? People you've rescued from a burning building? (I think this is always going to be a matter of opinion, and it's arguably not an English language question so much as one about etiquette or manners, but any additional information may help.)

Comment: People say “Thank you so much” when they feel that just saying “thank you” is insufficient.  Though, the more they use it, the more insufficient plain “thank you” feels.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a regional and even a micro-regional preference.  There is a small town near mine, containing many alternative lifestyle people -- and a lot of ordinary people too -- and I always know if someone is from that town because they never say, "thank you," but always say, "thank you so much."

When in Rome, you may want to do as the Romans, even if it's illogical.

Comment: You're probably slipping back into the mistake of stereotyping all Romans, or even those located in the capital, in your choice of adage. I'm thinking London's Eastenders ([UD](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=eastenders) is sparkling here) vs yuppies. // Probably belongs on 'Interpersonal Skills', but I can't remember an answer spelling out the need to consider 'regional and even a micro-regional preference[s]' so concisely, so I'll not vote to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

"Thank you" is the usual norm, "thank you so much" just adds a "gushing gratitude" which doesn't really do anything. They both can be used, it is a matter of preference and personal usage.